# Deviding Collection into dis-joint sub-collections counting

Tags: combinatorics

I have a collection with $n>0$ elements, wanted to divide them into some dis-joint non-empty collections such that the union of the collections is the original collection. This implies the number of sub-collections must be in $[1, n]$.

Question: how many different ways I can do the division? (same set of collections, but different order of the collection considered different, different order of elements in the collection is also count) I want a formula to calculate the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, so you want order in everything, just order the array and select points to break them. There are $n-1$ slots to break it and there are $n$ elements, so there must be $$\underbrace{n!}_{\text{order}}\underbrace{2^{n-1}}_{\text{  break}}$$ ways to do it.
 **Example:** $123,1|23,12|3,1|2|3,132,1|3|2,13|2,1|32,132\dots $